# Reset password token mismatch issue in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, token, reset

I'm building an app using Devise.
The problem I have is about the password reset process.

If the user forgets their password, enter the registered email address and send a password reset notice to that address.
So far it works as expected.

**problem**

The password reset token received in the email does not match the password reset token generated by the application.
So, when I try to reset the password from the email I received, I get the error "Token is invalid".

＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝

Show my code.

Gemfile

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'devise-i18n'
```

routes.rb

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
registrations: 'users/registrations',
sessions:      'users/sessions',
confirmations: 'users/confirmations',
omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks'
```

}

model/user.rb

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
          :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable,
          :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: %i[google_oauth2]


 def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.skip_confirmation!
    end
  end


  def update_without_current_password(params, *options)
    params.delete(:current_password)

    if params[:password].blank? && params[:password_confirmation].blank?

      params.delete(:password)
      params.delete(:password_confirmation)
    end

    result = update_attributes(params, *options)
    clean_up_passwords
    result
  end
```

views/users/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'パスワードの変更を行う', edit_password_url(@resource,reset_password_token: @token) %>
```

=========================================

I searched many times, but I couldn't find much new information because it was only old information.

Why don't the tokens match?
How can I email the generated tokens?
Please help someone.

※I'm not good at English. There may be mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new table for reset tokens.

schema can be like

```
password_reset_tokens
---------------------
id pk
reset_token unique string
user_id integer
is_active boolean
created_at datetime
updated_at datetime
```

whenever a user is going to request for a change password. Create an entry in this password_reset_tokens with a random reset_token string and assign a user_id to it.
send this token in the email with a link and when user is going to click on it the reset token. Open the form with new password fields and when password is updated through that link then mark is_active as false.

Additional step:

You can also write a cron to expire the reset_tokens after x hours. whenever a new reset_passsword_token is generated then you can schedule a cron to expire it after x hours.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. I already have a schema for t.string "reset_password_token", do I need to create a new one?

Comment: Do we have to create a new table or can we store this information in the user table?

Comment: Yeah you can create that, also instead of creating a cron you can create expired_at field instead of is_active and populate the time for expiry at the time of creation. So, that when user is verifying the token, you can check whether current time > expired time or not.